# See git commands generated by TortoiseGit

Tags: c#, .net, git, repository, tortoisegit

I use TortoiseGit as my git client. I can cooperate with repository by clicking. I would like to know more about git and its command.
Is there any oportunity to see what git commands are generate for git? For example I click Switch command and select target, how can I see command generated to git for this operation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enable *Debug mode* in *Turtoise settings*. Then you will be be able to track executed commands.

[image: settings]

Then you can capture debug by DebugView app. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647.aspx

[image: sample]

Comment: @Micky Duncan yeah, i dont know why, i will fix that. You can use DebugView application. https://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/wiki/HOWTO_Debug

Comment: unfortunately doesn't seem to work any more, latest link is also broken